# Как отслеживать обновление JSON данных с сервера

Tags: javascript, jquery

В течение дня у меня обновляется набор JSON данных.
Как я могу отслеживать изменения так, чтобы можно было реагировать на события обновления данных от сервера без перезагрузки браузера?

Comment: неплохое решение проверять через setInterval ?

Comment: Рассмотрите возможность использования технологии WebSokets или LongPolling.

Comment: @NeedHate
я считаю делать запрос на сервер даже с интервалом в минуту, лишняя нагрузка... хотелось бы, что бы JS срабатывал только тогда, когда JSON обновляется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если, сервер должен быть инициатором сообщения об изменении данных, то используйте websocket, иначе классические запросы.